# vscode customize theme color for selected item in autocomplete popup

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know there's the experimental setting "workbench.experimental.colorCustomizations" but I can't find any subsetting to change the background color of the currently selected item in the autocomplete popup.
Is there any other way to change this color?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```js
"editorSuggestWidget.background": "#424d66",// widget bg
"editorSuggestWidget.selectedBackground": "#29b6f6",// <-- this one -->
"editorSuggestWidget.highlightForeground": "#ff6a00",// typed(matching) symbols color
```

Comment: Yes, this option became available sometime during the April updates (1.12.x) but wasn't at the time of question. https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_12

Comment: And note that nowadays these settings are under "workbench.colorCustomizations" (not experimental any more)

Comment: Can I just say thank you? Every single time I have a VS code question, someone has an answer for it on Stackoverflow. People like you save people like me tons of time. It's appreciated.